# Replace url but keep the files names (AS3)

Tags: string, actionscript-3, url

I've got these urls taken from a website that have always the same path, only the name of the file is changing.

```
"http://www.swellmap.co.nz/style/img/weathericons/rain.png"
```

My AS3 code, is catching the url on this website everyday (weather).

I want to replace every icon with mine.

Is there a way to replace the path but keep the name of the file ? So I just have to upload a file with the same name :

Something like :

```
Url = "http://www.swellmap.co.nz/style/img/weathericons/rain.png";
myUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.nc/weather/";
Url.replace("http://www.swellmap.co.nz/style/img/weathericons/",myUrl); 
url_Icon= myUrl;
```

But how to tell "keep the end with the name file ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just define your own URLs?

Something like this should do it:

```
var myNewURL:String = Url.replace("http://www.swellmap.co.nz/style/img/weathericons/", myUrl);
```

If the part before the image name is not always the same:

```
// split the string by "/", this will result in ["http:", "", "www.swellmap.co.nz", "style", "img", "weathericons", "rain.png"]
// your imagename will be on the last position of the array
var urlSplit:Array = Url.split("/");

// get the image name from the last position of the array
var imageName:String = urlSplit[(urlSplit.length - 1)];

var newUrl:String = myUrl + imageName;
```